# Append to same line in Bash

Tags: bash, list, csv, sed, append

The file letters.csv contains:

```
b,a,c,
```

The file numbers.csv contains:

```
32
34
25
13
```

I would like to append numbers.csv to letters.csv like this:

```
b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```

I have tried this:

```
sed -e :a -e '{N; s/\n/,/g; ta}' numbers.csv >> letters.csv
```

However, this puts the appended entries on a new line:

```
b,a,c,
32,34,25,13
```

I would like all entries on the same line. How can this be done?

Comment: The append output redirect (`>>`) appends to wherever the end of the file is. If there's a newline there, appended data comes after that. If there's no trailing newline, appended bytes appear on the same line.

Comment: If I were you I'd append some letters to the numbers line, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `paste` alone.

First, convert contents in `numbers.csv` to comma-separated values. `-s` is the serial option and `-d,` specifies comma as delimiter:

```
$ paste -sd, numbers.csv
32,34,25,13
```

Then append this output to `letters.csv` by specifying an empty delimiter and [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
$ # use -d'\0' for non-GNU version of paste
$ paste -d '' letters.csv <(paste -sd, numbers.csv) > tmp && mv tmp letters.csv
$ cat letters.csv
b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```

To modify `sed` command posted in OP, use [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
$ sed -i -e "s/$/$(sed -e :a -e '{N; s/\n/,/g; ta}' numbers.csv)/" letters.csv
$ cat letters.csv
b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tr`:

```
cat letters.csv numbers.csv | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

(I hope this is not a useless use of `cat`. :-))

The `sed` at the end is needed to replace the last `,` with a newline character.

Comment: good one, can add `| sed 's/,$/\n/'` to remove trailing `,` and add newline instead :)

Comment: this will be probably the best solution if you include @Sundeep's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{printf "%s",$0; next} 
              {print $0} 
           END{ORS="\n"; print ""}' letters ORS=, numbers | 
  sed '$s/,$//'    # to delete last ","

b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{t=$0;next}{s=s","$0}END{print t s}' letters.csv numbers.csv
```

Comment: this is good alternate with awk, however it doesn't handle trailing `,` in letters.csv.. which is easy to fix with `awk 'FNR==NR{t=$0;next}{s=FNR==1?$0:s","$0}END{print t s}' letters.csv numbers.csv`