# Append to last line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, list, csv, append

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434000/append-to-same-line-in-bash).

The file `text.csv` contains:

```
#some text
some more text
b,a,c,
```

The file `numbers.csv` contains:

```
32
34
25
13
```

I would like to append `numbers.csv` to `text.csv` like this:

```
#some text
some more text
b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```

I have tried some of the recommendations in the linked example, but they tend to put everything on one line. I really want to append only to the last line. How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried? This Q will likely be voted as "asking for a tutorial" OR "too broad". Your Q needs to show specific code, with actual inputs, expected outputs, error messages and your thoughts about how you think it should work, v.s. how it is currently working. Read stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see what is expected for a Q here on StackOverflow. Don't expect people to go looking at links, you should include the relevant information in that link in the body of your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` and `paste` will solve this

```
$ sed '$s/$/'"$(paste -sd, numbers)"'/' letters

#some text
some more text
b,a,c,32,34,25,13
```